# Project Can not be created in Django

Tags: django

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 2, in 
from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Answer (score 0):

Did you pip install django?
**python -m pip install Django**